# Javascript Vue app multiuser Rest problem

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rest, supabase

I have an app created using VueJS that is used to schedule users in our organization. I am attempting to use server-less api, such as Supabase, as the database manager for the schedule "slots".  Since Vue (or JS in general) is a client side app, how can insure only one schedule "slot" will be allocated to a single user on submit request?

A little more explaination: The schedule's available "slots" are calculated at a GET request in the app when a single day is clicked on a calendar. The calculation is based on another table holding a date=num_slots. From there the user can click to schedule to slot, the request is sent, processed and after the response, the app makes another GET request to update the available slots to display in the client.  The problem -- If multiple users have their browsers open with the scheduling app, and they all select the same "slot", how can I prevent all of the requests from being posted to the database?

So maybe my logic is wrong?  Instead of *calculating* the open slots, I should be having a one-to-one record in the  "schedules" table. ie: 2023-10-29 | slot1, 2023-10-29 | slot2, etc. ?  That would return an error I could process successfully and prevent accidental over-scheduling, but makes creating the schedules table infinitely more difficult.

thanks for any solutions or feedback!
_mark

Answer (score 0):

```
‘’’ CREATE TABLE slots (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  date DATE,
  time TIME,
  status VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'available'
); ’’’
```

When a user requests a slot, you can:

```
1.  Check the status of the slot in the database.
2.  If it’s “available,” update the status to “locked” and associate it with the user.
3.  If it’s already “locked” or “booked” by another user, notify the current user that the slot is not available.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... I'm not sure that would solve my problem though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ... this kind of supports my solution of having a one-to-one setup instead of calculating the number of slots available based on other data.  Your suggestion would work for a table with all the slots pre-defined.  A little testing and this works good.  I'll need to create a routine to populate the slots table based on other data to minimize manual creation.